# Why does this PHP regex give me error?

Tags: php, regex

Need Some Help With Regex:

I want to replace

```
[url=http://youtube.com]YouTube.com[/url]
```

with

```
<a href="http://youtube.com">YouTube.com</a>
```

the regex

```
preg_replace("/[url=(.*?)](.*?)[/url]/is", '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $text);
```

why does this give me:

*Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'r' in C:\Programa\wamp\www\func.php on line 18*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should escape special characters in your regular expression:

```
preg_replace('/\[url=(.*?)](.*?)\[\/url]/is', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $text);
```

I have escaped the `[` characters (they specify the start of a character class) and the `/` character (it specifies the boundaries of the regular expression.)

Alternatively (for the `/` character) you can use another boundary character:

```
preg_replace('#\[url=(.*?)](.*?)\[/url]#is', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $text);
```

You still have to escape the `[` characters, though.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is interpreting the '`/`' in `/url` as being the end of the regex and the start of the regex options.  Insert a '`\`' before it to make it a literal '`/`'.

You need to escape the '`[`'s in the same way (otherwise they will be interpreted as introducing a character class).

```
preg_replace("/\[url=(.*?)](.*?)\[\/url]/is", '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $text);
```

Comment: Like: \[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]

Answer (score 0):

Both the slashes and square brackets are special characters in regex, you will need to escape them:

```
\/ \[ \]
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd '/' in a regex string ends the regex. You need to escape it. Also, preg_replace will interpret the '[url=(.*?)]' as a character class, so you need to escape those as well.

```
preg_replace('/\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/is', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be just starting out with regular expressions.  If that is the case - or maybe even if it isn't - you will find [the Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/) to be a very helpful tool.  It provides a sandbox for us to test our pattern matches and our replace strings too.   If you had been using that it would have highlighted the need to escape the special characters.